# After new install Android Studio: Migrate Project to Gradle? and Missing Configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I joined my pc to a domain, so I am a new user on my pc now. After this I can't open existing Android Studio Projects. I don't work often on my projects so most of the time Android Studio has a lot of updates; that could also be the cause.

However, when I try to open old projects I get the message **Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system.**

***Open existing Android Studio Project:***

[image: Migrate Project to Gradle?]

When I try to run or debug the project I get an **Edit Configuration** popup and I have no idea what is missing.

[image: Debug]

[image: Need to select Configuration?]

[image: Error message, output path]

[image: Project Structure]

I have upgraded to **Android Studio 3** and downgraded to **2.3** but it makes no difference. I know for sure that I have used Gradle in these projects. And I made backups of the entire directories so they are not corrupt.

When I create a new Android **sample-application** it's generated without problems and run in the simulator without issues:

[image: Hello World works fine]

I also tried:
***Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.).***

[image: Import project]

[image: Select Gradle?]

[image: Use Local Gradle Distribution?]

I also had at a look at these similar questions (see below) but they seem very specific. I tried to delete .**idea** (..etc. as mentioned) directories but this makes things worse.

[Migrate project to gradle error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094169/migrate-project-to-gradle-error)

and

[Can't migrate project to Gradle in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606504/cant-migrate-project-to-gradle-in-android-studio)

What makes it that these old projects can't be opened anymore?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of what you see in Android Studio?

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice, I added the pictures.

Comment: When you are importing your project select D:\Dev\As\..\Android app\source

Comment: In the Project Structure dialog (Alt+Ctrl+Shift+S) what are the Project settings? Your module settings indicate that it inherits the project's output settings.

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad Hannan solved this issue and I'm happy to mark it as answered if he will post his comment as an answer.

**I needed to open the 'source' directory in stead of the project-directory** and I can hardly belief that this leads to such problems. But is does. So when opening the project browse to the source directory, directly under the project-folder.

Thanks Muhammad.